# load images using php not direct access

Tags: php, image

I want to show images in my webpage using PHP not direct src like 'images/pic.jpg' .

But I have no idea about this it.

Would you help me?

I need the php script . please stop voting it down.

Edited:

Here's what I have tried :

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
readfile($imgsrc);
```

As this question is closed by someones, I have to say the answer I accepted and tried was right, the problem was open_basedir and file permission.

Problem is solved now.

but it out put error ' image cannot be displayed because it contains error'

Comment: Do you mean a PHP script to deliver images?

Comment: Yes, Why have someones voted to close my question ?

Comment: I'm guessing because it is not very clear?

Comment: @hd., What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [readfile:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

```
    function user_files($file_name = "")
    {
        // Check file_name is valid and only contains valid chars
        if ((preg_match('^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,32}+[.]{1}[A-Za-z]{3,4}$^', $file_name)) 
        {
               header('Content-Type: '.get_mime_by_extension(YOUR_PATH.$file_name)));
               readfile(YOUR_PATH.$file_name);
        }
    }
```

There is some issues around directory traversal etc - so you'll need to check the $file_name first like I have using the preg_match

Answer (score 0):

Put your images to a local directory (on server) which is inaccessible with HTTP protocol.

Then create a simple PHP script which will take file name as a parameter (or whatever else to identify which image you want to load) and returns the image instead of itself. I mean like http://www.server.com/imagescript.php?filename.jpg

It's extremely simple, you should be able to do it yourself. Or specify more details, what exactly is the problem for you.

Comment: Make sure to sanitize your path. Someone could pass `imagescript.php?i=/etc/php/php.ini` and start reading off arbitrary files from your OS.

Comment: Yes +1, everything passed in parameters must be used with maximum care. That's general rule.